# Symfony service container not overridding child class

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4

I am trying to override a service definition as per https://symfony.com/doc/2.4/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html#overriding-parent-dependencies
Here are my configs:

//services.yaml

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

imports:
    - {resource: 'clients.yaml'}
```

//clients.yaml

```
services:

    App\Api\Client\AbstractClient:
        abstract: true
        arguments:
            - '@serializer'
            - '@httplug.client.app'

    App\Api\Client\MyClient:
        parent: App\Api\Client\AbstractClient
        calls:
            - [setApiHost, ['%client.api_url%']]
```

As you can see I have two classes, of which one is an abstract parent.

This appears to be setup correctly (successfully overridden):

```
Information for Service "App\Api\Client\AbstractClient"
=======================================================

 ---------------- ------------------------------------------ 
  Option           Value                                     
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------ 
  Service ID       App\Api\Client\AbstractClient             
  Class            App\Api\Client\AbstractClient             
  Tags             -                                         
  Public           yes                                       
  Synthetic        no                                        
  Lazy             no                                        
  Shared           yes                                       
  Abstract         yes                                       
  Autowired        no                                        
  Autoconfigured   no                                        
  Arguments        Service(serializer)                       
                   Service(httplug.client.app.http_methods)
```

This class says its been autowired & autoconfigured but it has (correctly) inherited the arguments from my `AbstractClient`, but it has not implemented any setter injection definitions!

```
Information for Service "App\Api\Client\MyClient"
=========================================================

 ---------------- ------------------------------------------ 
  Option           Value                                     
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------ 
  Service ID       App\Api\Client\MyClient           
  Class            App\Api\Client\MyClient           
  Tags             -                                         
  Public           no                                        
  Synthetic        no                                        
  Lazy             no                                        
  Shared           yes                                       
  Abstract         no                                        
  Autowired        yes                                       
  Autoconfigured   yes                                       
  Arguments        Service(serializer)                       
                   Service(httplug.client.app.http_methods)
```

Can someone please guide me as to why my child class is not being correctly overridden?

Comment: I ended up just disabled auto-wiring for the `Api` directory.
`exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Api}'`

Comment: Always check the version number (in the upper right corner) of the documentation you are looking at.Looking at 2.4 docs for what looks like 3.4/4.0 can lead to all kinds of amusing adventures.